# Indent multiple lines within a list environment

Tags: lists, indentation

[image]
I would like the lines after the second line are indented from the left margin of the second line. The following method using `minipage` failed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item xxxxx\\ \href{https://www.google.com.tw/}{https://www.google.com.tw/}
\hfill\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-2em}
\lbrack While conventional search engines ranked results by counting how many times the search terms appeared on the page, the two theorized about a better system that analyzed the relationships among websites.\rbrack
\end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

`\hangindent` also failed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item xxxxx\\ \href{https://www.google.com.tw/}{https://www.google.com.tw/}\\ \hangindent=2em\hangafter=-3\lbrack While conventional search engines ranked results by counting how many times the search terms appeared on the page, the two theorized about a better system that analyzed the relationships among websites.\rbrack
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Off-topic: You have some questions with answers but did not accept one of them -- please go back to them and consider to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a nested itemize:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}

\item xxxxx\\
      \href{https://www.google.com.tw/}{https://www.google.com.tw/}
  \begin{itemize}[label={},nosep,leftmargin=2em]
  \item\relax [While conventional search engines ranked results by counting how many times
  the search terms appeared on the page, the two theorized about a better
  system that analyzed the relationships among websites.]
  \end{itemize}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]